# remove just all elements beginning with "id_"

Tags: jquery, element

For example, I have 2 elements like this:

```
<div id="id_1">ELement 1</div>
<div id="id_2">ELement 2</div>
<div id="not_id">different id</div>
```

how can I remove just all elements beginning with "id_",.?

thanks,.

Comment: by _remove_ do you mean hide from user or remove from DOM

Comment: I recommend taking an hour or two to thoroughly read through the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com It really only takes an hour or two, and it's hugely useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$("[id^='id_']").remove();
```

**Edit** (see comments)

Your question says "all elements", which is why the selector in my example is not as specific as it potentially could be. If you care about performance (in the real world, making this selector more specific is not going to make a noticable difference), then you should make your selector as specific as possible. If it is only `div` elements you care about, apply the "starts-with" selector to `div` elements only:

```
$("div[id^='id_']").remove();
```

Comment: `div[id^='id_']` would perform better

Comment: The questions says all elements, just his example uses divs.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('[id^="id_"]').remove();
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9tFE3/)